# Using regular expression metacharacters in grep

Tags: ubuntu, grep

As per the system: `cat /etc/lsb-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
```

On a Mac this seems pretty nice and working:

```
printf "12\na\na12\ndaab\n"|grep "\d"
```

I get:

```
12
na12
```

On the system described above, the same commands returns nothing.

Though regular expression are handled: `printf "12\na\na12\ndaab\n"|grep "^.$"`
gives:

```
a
```

Any explanation and solution?

**EDIT**

- grep (GNU grep) 2.16
- "\w" works like a charm

Comment: It would be nice to know what greps you are using. What does `grep --version` output for the two?

Comment: @sjsam Are you referring to the that first block of text? That's just information about his Linux system, not input to `grep`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have added that for the non working grep (the mac has `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`).

Comment: @AsTeR Is the objective to grab the lines containing only numbers?

Comment: @sjsam I made a short example to reproduce the problem, lines with at least one number was the target of the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `\d` to work you need to use Perl style regular  expression.

```
printf "12\na\na12\ndaab\n" | grep -P '\d'
```

gives

```
12
a12
```

---

An alternative would be

```
printf "12\na\na12\ndaab\n" | grep -E '[[:digit:]]+'
```

which gives

```
12
a12
```

---

<sup>**Warning:** As grep manpage says, Perl style  regular  expression is highly experimental</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Very few tools will recognize `\d` as meaning a digit and it's just a couple of characters briefer than the obvious and universally working `[0-9]` so just use that everywhere for portability:

```
$ printf "12\na\na12\ndaab\n"|grep "[0-9]"
12
a12
```

Note that in theory you should use the character class `[:digit:]` instead but I've never heard of a locale where that's not the same set of characters as `[0-9]` and it won't be accepted by ALL greps so YMMV wrt the benefits of using that.